# Nestjs passport-jwt ignore JWT signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, passport.js, nestjs, passport-jwt

I can't pass any secret here, because it is stored in Redis for each user and I have to parse the token body before I can access the user id to get their secret. Using nestjs for architecture. Are there any elegant solutions without having to write whole copy of the strategy by myself?

````
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: ???,
      passReqToCallback: true,
    });
  }

  async validate(req: any, payload: UserType): Promise<UserType> {
    try {
      const token = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()(req);

      const [header, body] = token.split('.');

      const headerJSON = JSON.parse(btoa(header)) as { alg: Algorithm };
      const bodyJSON = JSON.parse(btoa(body)) as UserType;

      const sub = bodyJSON.sub;

      const userId = await this.authService.findUserSecret(sub);

      const jwt = new JwtService({
        secret: userId,
      });

      await jwt.verify(token, {
        algorithms: [headerJSON.alg],
      });

      return payload;
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject();
    }
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performed a bit more research and found this

```
      secretOrKeyProvider(request: any, rawJwtToken: string, done: any) {
        const [, body] = rawJwtToken.split('.');

        const bodyJSON = JSON.parse(btoa(body)) as UserType;

        const { sub } = bodyJSON;

        authService
          .findUserSecret(sub)
          .then(secret => secret || Promise.reject())
          .then(secret => done(null, secret))
          .catch(error => done(error, null));
      },
```